# Restart Hazelcast Jet (v0.4) when there is an exception

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

We are using Hazelcast Jet 0.4 version to read messages from Kafka Source, process the messages and write to Kafka.
Since Kafka is managed by an external team, we could not control various exceptions thrown in Kafka.

For example, we receive the following exception: **Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions**

When we receive this error Hazelcast Jet instance is shutdown. So our application becomes unusable and we have to restart the application.

We are looking at the possibilities to restart the Jet instance automatically during these errors.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you suffer from this issue: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/issues/428. It is fixed in current Jet version where manual partition assignment is used and even very slow processing of the events won't cause heartbeat timeout.